# C# Google analytics Event Category is empty

Tags: c#, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I try to add some Event Tracking through my C# code.

Here is my code:

Class GoogleTracker:

```
public class GoogleTracker
{
    private string googleURL = "www.google-analytics.com";
    private string googleVersion = "1";
    private string googleTrackingID = "UA-73897840-1";
    private string googleClientID = "efb9a302-9712-40c1-acd2-590764526665";

    public GoogleTracker() { }

    public void trackEvent(string category, string action, string label, string value)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "event");                   // Event hit type
        ht.Add("ec", category);                 // Event Category. Required.
        ht.Add("ea", action);                   // Event Action. Required.
        if (label != null) ht.Add("el", label); // Event label.
        if (value != null) ht.Add("ev", value); // Event value.

        postData(ht);
    }
    public void trackPage(string hostname, string page, string title)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "pageview");                // Pageview hit type.
        ht.Add("dh", hostname);                 // Document hostname.
        ht.Add("dp", page);                     // Page.
        ht.Add("dt", title);                    // Title.

        postData(ht);
    }

    public void ecommerceTransaction(string id, string affiliation, string revenue, string shipping, string tax, string currency)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "transaction");       // Transaction hit type.
        ht.Add("ti", id);                 // transaction ID.            Required.
        ht.Add("ta", affiliation);        // Transaction affiliation.
        ht.Add("tr", revenue);            // Transaction revenue.
        ht.Add("ts", shipping);           // Transaction shipping.
        ht.Add("tt", tax);                // Transaction tax.
        ht.Add("cu", currency);           // Currency code.

        postData(ht);
    }
    public void ecommerceItem(string id, string name, string price, string quantity, string code, string category, string currency)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "item");              // Item hit type.
        ht.Add("ti", id);                 // transaction ID.            Required.
        ht.Add("in", name);               // Item name.                 Required.
        ht.Add("ip", price);              // Item price.
        ht.Add("iq", quantity);           // Item quantity.
        ht.Add("ic", code);               // Item code / SKU.
        ht.Add("iv", category);           // Item variation / category.
        ht.Add("cu", currency);           // Currency code.

        postData(ht);
    }

    public void trackSocial(string action, string network, string target)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "social");                // Social hit type.
        ht.Add("dh", action);                 // Social Action.         Required.
        ht.Add("dp", network);                // Social Network.        Required.
        ht.Add("dt", target);                 // Social Target.         Required.

        postData(ht);
    }

    public void trackException(string description, bool fatal)
    {
        Hashtable ht = baseValues();

        ht.Add("t", "exception");             // Exception hit type.
        ht.Add("dh", description);            // Exception description.         Required.
        ht.Add("dp", fatal ? "1" : "0");      // Exception is fatal?            Required.

        postData(ht);
    }

    private Hashtable baseValues()
    {
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Add("v", googleVersion);         // Version.
        ht.Add("tid", googleTrackingID);    // Tracking ID / Web property / Property ID.
        ht.Add("cid", googleClientID);      // Anonymous Client ID.
        return ht;
    }
    private bool postData(Hashtable values)
    {
        string data = "";
        foreach (var key in values.Keys)
        {
            if (data != "") data += "&";
            if (values[key] != null) data += key.ToString() + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(values[key].ToString());
        }

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = client.UploadString(googleURL, "POST", data);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

My Program class:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        GoogleTracker ga = new GoogleTracker();
        ga.trackEvent("Event", "Click", "", "5");
    }
}
```

The code works without exception. However when I see in my report page (https://analytics.google.com/analytics/), my Event Category and Event Action are still empty.
[image]

I dont understand why no data. Is there any error?

Comment: How long did you wait it takes 24 -48 hours for data to show up in standard reports.  Did you try the real-time reports?

Comment: Did you try validating the hit before you send it? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits

Comment: @DaImTo really? it's so long. I have been waiting in few minutes. How to do the real-time reports? Do you have any reference?

Comment: in the left hand menu scroll up look for Real-time -> events

Comment: @DaImTo I found a reference using c# just to get data and display it (http://www.daimto.com/googleAnalytics-realtime-csharp/). I want to send (post) the real-time data. Is there any sample code?

Comment: @DaImTo how to validate the data before send it? (C# code please). I have no experience in javascript.

Comment: probably by editing your postData() method and adding debug to the call and checking what it returns.  Its just a change in the end point to the call.

Comment: @DaImTo Today, I see the data in the report. Yes, it takes so long to show up the data.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that it can take 24 - 48 hours for data to show in the standard reports.  For debugging you can check the real-time reports this will show you if your requests are being received.

My Validate hit method.

```
  public static object send(string postData, bool isValidate)
        {
            string url = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
            if (isValidate)
            {
                url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect";
            }

            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.

            request.Method = "POST";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValidateResponse>(responseFromServer);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("SendHitFailed",ex);
            }          
        }
```

Validate response class

```
 public class ValidateResponse
    {
        public List<HitParsingResult> hitParsingResult { get; set; }
        public List<ParserMessage2> parserMessage { get; set; }

        public class ParserMessage
        {
            public string messageType { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string messageCode { get; set; }
            public string parameter { get; set; }
        }

        public class HitParsingResult
        {
            public bool valid { get; set; }
            public List<ParserMessage> parserMessage { get; set; }
            public string hit { get; set; }
        }

        public class ParserMessage2
        {
            public string messageType { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My code returns true in method postData; so there is no error, the problem is posting? And what is "googleURL"? My googleURL "www.google-analytics.com" is correct? The googleClientID can be a random character? I see the sample code is using "555".

Comment: posting to http://www.google-analytics.com/collect is a actual hit posting to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect is a debug hit.   collect always returns true it doesn't return errors it just trys to eat what you send it.

Comment: cid can be what every you want really https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid